# Do you use a CSS framework?

Tags: css, frameworks

If yes, which one? Why?
If no, why? How do you fix cross browser CSS rendering?

I currently use blueprint css, and I wonder if it's a good choice. Thanks!
:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, I'm not using any framework, just a well thought out naming system that I reuse over and over and a basic css with a few resets and some base styles.

Why am I not using a css framework?

The use of a framework usually assumes that the designer is familiar with its conventions which is quite often not the case - you're not the one designing the page or the client has his own designer. And even if this is not the case, there will always be designs that won't fit into 960 pixels or simply have an even size so you can't use your magical .span-4 class.

Which leads me to the next point. The naming is not semantic. In theory you would expect a framework to ease maintaining a large site. However, suppose you have to make a slight design change. This basically means changing the html across all the template views involved. This is hard and risky even with a versioning system, because it's one thing having to rollback to a single css file, and another to 100 views. All because input.span-19 should have 5pixels less. CSS frameworks - the new inline css.

What about cross browser issues? Either you're using a framework or not this is not going to change. There are browsers or operating systems that have certain particularities. Bottom line - Internet Explorer will still suck as much.

CSS Frameworks stand out for discipline and I have to give them credit for that, but in the end it's all about the one writing the code.

Comment: +1 for explaining issues with CSS frameworks.

Comment: completely right. I used 960gs once on larger project, and encountered all of the mentioned issues.

Comment: One point I disagree with:  cross-browser compatibility.  My choices boil down to keeping the design simple enough to evade all issues, OR learning all the ins, outs and hacks of CSS, OR using a tool like Grid 960 that has the solutions wonderfully built in.  Grid 960 delivers the same results with one percent discrepancy between FireFox and IE7, which is way more than I could achieve otherwise.  (God bless Nathan Smith for creating Grid 960.)

Comment: Your well thought out naming system that you reuse over and over is a framework by definition. You are using a framework!

Comment: id rather workaround browser bugs i know then workaround bootstrap bugs!

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed two major misconceptions about css frameworks.

Firstly, there tends to a lot of confusion between the concept of a framework used in software development, as a tool and a type of a framework such as 960gs.

[Wikipedia defines a framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) as "an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by user code, thus providing application specific software".

@vise says "I'm not using any framework, just a well thought out naming system that I reuse over and over and a basic css with a few resets and some base styles." This is akin to saying "I'm not using any framework, just a framework." This is probably some kind of semantic irony. No offence intended :)

Blueprint, 960, compass etc are all types of frameworks. Because some css frameworks may not be semantic or are lacking certain desirable qualities, this does not mean css frameworks are a bad idea.

The second misconception is that css and css frameworks are mutually exclusive. You either code css by hand or you use a framework (with some custom stuff). But... wait a minute... isn't CSS a set of default elements that we can alter or extend to suit our specific requirements? CSS looks suspiciously like a framework according to Wikipedia's definition.

Of course, this second point is debatable. But often I find that people are using some kind of framework without knowing it.

To answer your question, I tend to use something like [sass](http://sass-lang.com) and make [my own framework](https://github.com/rimian/css-framework). On my latest project, I am using a combination of this and [Bourbon](http://www.thoughtbot.com/bourbon/) which is looking good so far. The main reason I use frameworks is because I'm tired of the redundancy in CSS. It's really boring having to repeat the same values over and over. There are other concepts in design that CSS doesn't do very well which I won't go into here (see [here](http://rimian.com.au/best-practice-css.pdf)). But by using a framework, it's possible to abstract all your problems away and just work on getting things done.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I like the [yui css](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) tools. Those guys have definitely spent more time dealing with cross browser css than I would care to. I haven't tried others.

Answer (score 3):

I use yahoo's [yui-css](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/) framework. That's the first one I came across and it was easy to understand. I just saw the video and cheatsheet and got it working.Also, Yahoo uses it on some of their sites.

Answer (score 2):

I use Blueprint along with the [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) framework. Coding CSS has become enjoyable again. :-)

Comment: I didn't heard of Compass and Sass. Looks very interesting. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem. I hope you enjoy it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Compass/Sass combination is fantastic, and offers several plugins for using the framework of your choice without the non-semantic class names. Outside of Compass, I always found frameworks to be too restrictive and use too much markup.

I'm not a fan of the Blueprint, 960gs and YUI plugins for Compass either: they were originally built for use with extra markup and don't take full advantage of Compass/Sass for extra flexibility. So I built '[Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/)' - a flexible framework built native to Compass/Sass.

Whatever plugin you use (or write your own), I highly recommend Compass/Sass as a better option than extra markup.

Comment: fixed, thanks: http://susy.oddbird.net/

Answer (score 1):

I created my own subset of classes from which i found myself use very frequently, this makes me work faster and create html layouts much easier, without repeating same properties under a lot of classes.

For example for inline divs i have fl and fr classes to represent float right and left, for fluid widths i have 20 width classes. Here are some classes from my generic stylesheet i mentioned. It works out for me.

```
.fl { display:inline; float:left;}
.fll { display:inline!important; float:left!important;}
.fr { display:inline; float:right}
.frr { display:inline!important; float:right!important;}
.ib { display: -moz-inline-block; display:inline-block;}
.clear { clear: both}
.none {display:none;}
.noni {display: none!important;}
.block {display:block;}
.blocki {display: block!important;}
.pointer {cursor: pointer !important;}
...
.w10 { width: 10% !important; }
.w15 { width: 15% !important; }
.w20 { width: 20% !important; }
.w25 { width: 25% !important; }
...
```

So this technique can't be a framework replacement of course, but this works well enough if you don't want to have any other thing in between your styles and you:)

Sinan.

P.S. In IE6 and below multiple classes work buggy this is to use in modern browsers. see [the table at Quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Blueprint-css at some places and found it quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [960 Grid System](http://960.gs) is an effort to streamline web development workflow by providing commonly used dimensions, based on a width of 960 pixels. There are two variants: 12 and 16 columns, which can be used separately or in tandem.

I prefer fluid version of 960.gs: [Fluid 960 Grid System](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)

Answer (score 0):

Just started a project using 960 grid. The designer bought into this early on, and let it guide his designs.

I must say, it's much much faster. Spend much less time measuring pixels on mockups, asking the designer the intent, and futzing with CSS to build "page templates". Spend much more time just implementing the designs.

Answer (score 0):

I use a few on a regular basis and I would recommend checking them out.

[heymuscle](http://heymuscle.com) is a responsive css framework that fits 1140px/960px/ipad/iphone similar to 960gs

[960 grid](http://960.gs) is one of the most popular grid's out there and provides easy to use classes for laying out your page

[1140 grid](http://cssgrid.net) is a fluid layout

Hope this helps